# Regarding SQLl*Plus set statements

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus, sql-scripts

I am spooling from a sql script. when sql statement executes the variable substitution it displays it. how can i turn it off. it displays the below along with the csv contents.

```
old  12: where file_id = '&a_file_id' --1=1
new  12: where file_id = '36145' --1=1
D,A002,RENT  ,0240286148, Access  Zone ,Rent,3200,320,320
```

I have the below setting but still it's not turning it off.

```
        SET FEEDBACK OFF
        SET HEADING OFF
        SET LINESIZE 800
        SET PAGESIZE 0
        SET TRIMSPOOL ON
        SET TERMOUT OFF
        SET ECHO OFF
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your missing statement is

```
SET VERIFY OFF
```

which suppresses the details of the substitution.